# Automate sequence of different remote control presses

Tags: software-defined-radio, remote-control

I've got the following setup I would like to automate:

- Press button A on a remote to turn the alarm system off
- Press button A on a remote to open the garage door
- Press button A on a remote to close the garage door
- Press button B on a remote to turn the alarm system on

In between those steps, I could include a step to press a button on a third remote to turn on/off the car alarm.

I'm a newbie in both RF and electrical engineering, so any bits of advice would be very greatly appreciated.

I see three possible solutions for my problem, unfortunately, one of them I cannot apply:

- I - (most preferable, as I can keep the remotes out of the garage) - simulate the presses by sending a signal from a Hack RF place inside the garage. The signals will be chained and depending on one another.
- II - (not preferable, as the remotes have to physically be in the garage) - by using [solenoids](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11015) controlled by a Raspberry Pi and placed next to the remotes, those solenoids to actually press the remotes but the whole process to be started externally.
- III - (this would void the warranty so it's not applicable) - open the plastic cases of the remotes, and through soldering / desoldering simulate button press through a Raspberry Pi.

I've watched some tutorials, made my research so decided to proceed with the option I. Bought me a Hack RF and started my struggle to reproduce the signal, unfortunately, I'm still failing but this could be due to lack of knowledge or experience on my side.
An issue to add on top of the situation - I'm pretty sure some of the remotes are using a rolling code, so simulating the signal won't be that easy...

Coming to my question - do you think option I is doable at all?
Should I keep trying to replicate the signal, then the second one and so on until I eventually reach the point where I can replicate and chain the successful sequence?

Should I go for a different option or there is something I'm missing and you would advise me to do?   Thanks! :)

Comment: the signal from  the remote control may be encrypted ...... this may be an example of an `X-Y problem` .... you are asking for help with what you consider to be a solution to an unspecified problem even though the solution may be misguided ........ what problem are you trying to solve? (why are you trying to automate the button presses?)

Comment: You could describe (a) the model of alarm and remotes and (b) what you have done to either research or detect and measure the signals between the remote and the alarm/door system.

Comment: @jsotola I'm trying to figure out if my approach is correct and if it would make sense to keep trying. I'm trying to automate the procedure to A - easy my life and because it's something I would like to do in my spare time and B - I won't have to carry two or more remotes with me all the time.

Comment: @gwideman the remote is a Novotron 522 operating a Novoferm motor which lifts the door (https://www.meurer-shop.de/tor-antriebe/novoferm-siebau/zubehoer/2-kanal-novoferm-mini-novotron-522-handsender).

Comment: @gwideman The car alarm remote is unspecified, but here a couple of pictures of its board - https://photos.app.goo.gl/Aneqo7XC7dsu3GBf6

So far I've tried to intercept the signal going from the remote to the receiver with a HackRf SDR, decode the signal and then send a new signal with the hope this will open the door/stop the alarm. This doesn't work unfortunately so then I tried to record the signal and replay it when near. This failed again.

Comment: the novotron site product description says `AES 128 bit-Verschlüsselung` ... my guess is that it may be difficult to crack the encryption .... I wonder if the garage door opener has an aux channel that could be used to operate the alarm system